# Ajax posting and getting from mvc controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

All I want to do is post a zipcode to a controller, do some stuff to the zipcode, and post back the changes to the zipcode. But my parameter a is always null. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

View:

```
<input type="text" id="zipcode" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var serviceURL = '/Employer/employer/index';
        var zipcode = $("#zipcode").val();

        $("#zipcode").blur(function () {
            $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceURL,
        data: {'a':zipcode},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });

    function successFunc(data, status) {
        alert(data);
    }

    function errorFunc() {
        alert('error');
    }
    });
    });
```

Controller:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string a)
{
    return Json("test", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: '/Employer/employer/index' is not a file. It should be `index.php` or something, add the extension.

Comment: You're including jQuery twice in your page - remove one of them. It may not be the root of your problem, but it certainly won't be helping

Comment: @JeremyThille no it shouldn't, that's not how asp.net-MCV works

Comment: Okay! I had no clue.

Comment: "Parameter 'a' is always null"  means `$("#zipcode").val()` is null. Can you add your HTML code?

Comment: @Kevin try removing the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` line. It may be confusing the MVC model binder.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This fixed the issue! Thanks! if you make this an answer I will select it as best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are including two versions of jQuery in your page, I strongly suggest you remove one. Use `1.9` if you want to support IE9 and lower, `2.0`+ if you don't support legacy browsers.

Also, when jQuery serialises the `data` provided it is not necessarily sent in JSON format, so the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` setting may be confusing the MVC model binder, remove it.

Finally, note that `zipcode` is only set on page load, you should also retrieve it before the AJAX request is sent.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that you are storing zipcode value into the variable right in the document.ready handler, before user had a chance to interact with it. You should do this in the blur handler, to make sure you take the actual value:

```
$("#zipcode").blur(function () {
    var zipcode = $("#zipcode").val();
    $.ajax({
```

Comment: That is correct. zipcode is initialized once, and is empty (because it's just the page load). Then, the input value is never updated again; it's just sent empty.